# Find a matrix M for an iterative method with spectral radius greater than 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, spectral-radius

I have been trying to find a matrix $M$ with a size 3 x 3 for an iterative method $x_k = Mx_k +b$ with a spectral radius of M greater than 1, where in two instances the iteration converges based on the $x_0$ and $b$. And also diverges based on the $x_0$ and $b$. However, I don't really know how to find one that converges, since all the theorems I found state that the spectral radius of M is less than 1, then the iterative method converges. Is there any examples you guys can give me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: take
$$
M = \pmatrix{1/2&0&0\\0&1/2&0\\0&0&2}, \quad b = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}.
$$
The sequence will converge to the limit $x = 2b$ if and only if the last entry of $x_0$ is $0$.

Comment: How can I prove that this iterative method converges without using the spectral radius theorem?

Comment: @user3002936 Try to find a formula for $x_k$ in terms of $x_0$; it's easy in this case because the matrix $M$ is diagonal. If you want to make the formula a bit simpler, you could always take $b = (0,0,0)$ instead.

Comment: Do you mean like $x_{k+1} = Mx_k + b$?

Comment: In case you're curious, here's the formula for the $M,b$ that I chose:
$$
\pmatrix{x_k(1)\\x_k(2)\\ x_k(3)} = \pmatrix{2^{-k}(x_0(1) - 2) + 2\\ 2^{-k}x_0(2)\\ 2^kx_0(3)}.
$$

Comment: @user3002936 That's not a formula for $x_k$ in terms of $x_0$, that's a formula for $x_{k+1}$ in terms of $x_{k}$ (or equivalently for $x_k$ in terms of $x_{k-1}$).

Comment: I'm really curious. Could you tell me how you formulated that equation? I'm really confused. Thanks!

Comment: Write out the matrix equation and you end up with three separate equations:
$$
\pmatrix{x_{k+1}(1)\\  x_{k+1}(2) \\ x_{k+1}(3)} = 
\pmatrix{\frac 12 x_k(1) + 1\\ \frac 12 x_k(2) \\ 2 x_k(3)} \implies\\
\begin{cases}
x_{k+1}(1) = \frac 12 x_k(1) + 1\\
x_{k+1}(2) = \frac 12 x_k(2)\\
x_{k+1}(3) = 2 x_k(3).
\end{cases}
$$
The equation for $x_k(1)$ is a bit trickier, but I think you would be able to solve the second and third equation on your own if you give it a try.

Comment: I could kind of see how you would get the second and third equations. But could you give a little more details where it leads to converging to 2b?

Comment: @user3002936 For the purposes of a proof, you could just prove that the equation is correct by plugging in. If you insist on deriving the expression, you could use the steps [outlined here](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/peter/491/diff.pdf).

Comment: I guess I'm wondering how I can prove that this iterative method converges based on the M, $x_0$ and $b$?

Comment: @user3002936 Once you have the formula, it's clear that when $x_0(3) = 0$, we have $\lim_{k \to \infty}x_k(i) = 0$ for $i = 1,2,3$. I don't know what standards your instructor has, but it is probably the case that you can state that this is the limit (after giving the formula and possibly proving that the formula is correct by plugging in, as I suggested) without any further proof.

Comment: Right, I understand that part. I was just curious about how did you know to come up with the first equation? I tried to do that, but I'm having no luck. I got the limit as 2 for the first equation. So I'm kind of confused.

Comment: There's a trick for recurrence relations of the form
$$
u_{k+1} = a u_k + b.
$$
Look for a constant solution $u_k = C$, then the solution will be
$$
u_k = a^k(u_0 - C) + C.
$$
The trick is a little bit more general than that; what I do more generally is a discrete version of the [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients).

Comment: I see. That makes sense, I need to work that out. What about $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} 2^{−}(_k(1)−2)+2 =2$. This does not equal to 0.

Comment: @user3002936 Sorry, we should actually have $x_k(i) \to x(i)$, where $x$ denotes the limit of the sequence and, as I said, we have $x = 2b$. So, $x_k(1) \to 2 \cdot 1 = 2$, as should be the case

Comment: Okay that makes sense now. But I thought that in order for a sequence to converge, the limit needs to be 0.

Comment: @user3002936 No, a sequence converges whenever it has an actual limit

Comment: Okay, I see. Sorry I got confused with your earlier comment. I was thinking about series. Then how does this guarantee that the iterative method converges then? Like in your comment earlier you said that any $x_0$ works as long as the last element is 0. Why is that the case? Then if the last element is not 0, does that mean the iterative method diverges?

Comment: @user3002936 If $x_0(3) \neq 0$, then $x_k(3) = 2^k x_0(3)$ does not converge. Otherwise, each of the entries converge, so the sequence corresponding to the iterative method converges.

Comment: Could you explain how $x_k(3)$ converges when $x_0(3)=0$? I did the limit proof, but I got that it diverges since $2^k$ grows exponentially large, so I'm confused on why this converges and the second diverges when it is not equal to 0. Thanks!

Comment: If $x_0(3)$, then we have $x_k(3) = 2^k \cdot 0 = 0$. That is, we have $x_k(3) = 0$ for all $k$. Of course, this sequence converges to zero. For any other initial value of $x_0(3)$, $x_k(3)$ will grow exponentially large, as you've said.